# Live Video Broadcasting android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am developing an android application that will do live video broadcasting from mobile camera to Nimble streaming server. I have done google and find this link

http://www.walking-productions.com/notslop/2013/01/16/android-live-streaming-courtesy-of-javacv-and-ffmpeg/comment-page-2/#comment-428898

Actually i have downloaded project and successfully imported it on my eclipse , but when i am changing url from

```
rtmp://live:live@128.122.151.108:1935/live/test.flv
```

to

```
 rtmp://192.168.1.51:1935/magnify/sudeep
```

The camera started but it does not do live streaming. On seeing it on my log cat output i got this following error:

```
07-16 13:56:13.314: W/System.err(22490): com.googlecode.javacv.FrameRecorder$Exception: av_interleaved_write_frame() error -32 while writing interleaved audio frame.
07-16 13:56:13.314: W/System.err(22490): at com.googlecode.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder.record(FFmpegFrameRecorder.java:747)
```

Actually i am using Nimble streaming server as My server. Actually i got stuck it into from last 3 days.

Comment: Im using this same example with  ngnix and wowza  server and its is working well for me.

Comment: which format of server url u r using can u mention it here

Comment: Just configure the server and give the correct url

Comment: Sorry man i cant share my url,use wowza server,it is very easy to integrate

Comment: @Giridharan: please provide ur email id so we can discuss it in detail

Comment: @ Giridharan i have sent u a request please accept it

Comment: please check the format of my url is it anything wrong

Comment: After broadcasting did you check the play back in vlc player

Comment: could we continue discussion on gmail please

Comment: I didn't receive any mail yet

Comment: i have sent a request on google hangout  please check it